# Auto Deploy to WebShere v6.1 through IBM RSA IDE

Tags: maven-2, websphere, rational-rsa

Is there a way to do an automatic deployment to my local rsa web sphere 6.1 instance that runs within rsa? I have maven build script already, not sure if I can integrate something into there? Or is there some sort of batch script that I can make? Each time I make changes, I'm doing a build, and than manually updating the war file through the rsa administrative console and it requires a lot of clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Why not use maven to deploy this to the WAS Test environment?

There are a number o articles that show how to deploy EARs/WARs to WAS using maven.

(2) Alternatively try and use WRD (WebSphere Rapid Deployment. In this case, WAS monitors a folder, maven can create the EARs and WARs in that monitored folder and let WAS do a deployment under the hood for those EARs and WARs.

(3) You can also turn on auto publishing in the Test environment settings so that you don't need to click so many time when the build occurs.

HTH
Manglu